# Example of non noetherian ring and noetherian $\Bbb Z$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

> 1. a non Noetherian ring that is a Noetherian $\Bbb Z$-module
> 2. a Noetherian ring that is a non Noetherian $\Bbb Z$-module

I have no idea in 1, and I'm not sure if $\mathbf{Q}$ is right for 2?

Answer (score 5):

Given a ring $R$ that's Noetherian as a $\Bbb Z$-module, it's automatically a (left- or right- as desired) Noetherian ring, as ideals are by definition closed under sum of elements; so every increasing chain of ideals is an increasing chain of $\Bbb Z$-submodules of $R$, and thus stabilizes.

$\Bbb Q$ is indeed a Noetherian ring (it only has two ideals) that's not Noetherian as a $\Bbb Z$-module (consider $(1) \subset (1/2) \subset (1/4) \subset \dots$); we actually know explicitly [what the Noetherian $\Bbb Z$-modules are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group#Classification).